# How do I provide SSO for our ROR and JavaEE applications?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, jakarta-ee

We have two application one is in Ruby On Rails and second is in Java EE.

We want to integrate those two application so that if user has done login in one of them other one should be accessible without login.

How can we implement this??

this two applications are running on different servers, ROR on webrick and Java EE (JBoss or Tomcat)

What are the various ways to integrate such applications??

Comment: If I want to implement all this SSO functionality in JAVA then what would be the best strategy to do this? I have seen memcached-session-manager to do this task.. Is there any other way out??

Comment: The title should be "How do I provide SSO for our ROR and JavaEE applications?" You seem to only care about your users of ROR or Java app being able to login to either system, and seamlessly access the other system without logging in again.

This really is not about application integration :-(

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called Single Sign On, and the there are practically infinity answers to how you could do it.  This question will probably be closed.

But, if you want one (of the many possible) solutions, you could run a JBoss PicketLink server for Identity Management.  Expose a SOAP API from the PicketLink server, and then consume that one the Rails side for authentication/authorization.

Comment: Sir the Single Sign On idea was rejected by our manager that is why i m finding some other solution

Comment: Well, that's just the just the name of the concept of what you want. SSO mean signs in one place, be logged into another different place.

Answer (score 1):

As @messick mentioned you will have to go for a SSO (Single Sign On implement ion), There are standard libraries for that and the most famous is [CAS (ruby)](https://code.google.com/p/rubycas-server/)

You could either implement the CAS server in JAVA and use a ruby client or CAS server is ruby with a java client

This is the [standard CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas) guidelines project (you could find links to implementation in various languages as well)